# Identifying 14-pin DFN14 SMD with marking 9255 -GE708

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

There is an SMD component on this keypad  PCB that I think is a 14-pin DFN14, and the marking is 9255 GE708 . Does anyone know what this component is?
The Pins traces are going to MCU.

[image]

Comment: electronix - This is now the second of your identification questions where you have removed the photo. I have rolled-back that edit, since the photo is an important part of the question for future readers. Please do not remove the photo again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be an [Infineon TLE9255W](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE9255W-DataSheet-v01_04-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625bd71aa0015c10eaeaf93ee5), which is a CAN transciever. The logo appears to be an infineon-logo, and 9255 matches the part number. It might be a counterfeit chip, as the markings are a bit odd. The datasheet clearly states that the markings should be 9255W.

Most of the surrounding components makes sense (large cap between Gnd and Vcc on pins 2 and 3, series resistors on TxD and RxD on pins 1 and 4, cap on pin 5), although pins 12 and 13 appear at first glance to be connected to a crystal (X3). These pins are the CANL and CANH pins, so X3 might be the optional common mode choke mentioned in the application example in the datasheet (and the component looks more like a choke than a crystal), although I'm not sure if C54 and C55 makes sense then.